# How do you force C++ compilation on a .c file using VxWorks MIPS compiler?

Tags: compiler-construction, mips, vxworks

I'm using the VxWorks MIPS compiler and I have some third party source that needs to be compiled as c++ but all the extensions are .c.  There must be a switch I can pass into the compiler in this case to force C++ compilation but I can't find it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Is the VxWorks MIPS compiler just gcc with a different name?  If so you might be able to give it the flag `-x c++` to explicitly specify the language rather than letting the compiler choose a default based on the file name suffix.

Answer (score 0):

One trick is to create a meta file that includes all the 3rd party source and rename it .cpp/.cc.  Something like:

`find 3rd_party -type f -name '*\.c' | awk '{print "#include \"" $0 "\""}' > build_3rd_party.cc`

You'll have to make sure all the -I's line up and mess with the compile flags they want.  This will also speed things up a bit if there are piles of subdirectories to recurse through.

Failing that, pass a new CC env var to make for the 3rd party stuff which really points to the cpp compiler.